# Cómo utilizar la biblioteca externa de tipo .jar en el código de Visual Studio?

Tags: java, vscode

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto de Java, y quiero añadir una biblioteca para complementar el código. No estoy pidiendo la recomendación de biblioteca, pero quiero añadir la biblioteca .jar que ya está en mi ordenador para el proyecto.

Cómo puedo agregar la biblioteca en el proyecto y así tirar de su valor? He creado una carpeta con el nombre JAVA y en esa carpeta todas las clases .java como pueden ver ABAJO:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tiene algún recurso en el IDE `Visual Studio Code` que me posibilite usar medios externos? Como una biblioteca .jar? Así como en Eclipse, Netbeans y tantas otras IDEs? Porque sé que `Visual Studio Code` es diferente del `IDE Visual Studio`.

En primer lugar, no estoy pidiendo sugerencia y recomendación, sólo estoy apuntando a una solución dentro del software. Si alguien puede ayudar, gracias.

Comment: Mira esta [guía en inglés](https://blog.usejournal.com/visual-studio-code-for-java-the-ultimate-guide-2019-8de7d2b59902). Aquí explica todo acerca de usar Java con Visual Studio Code, incluído el importar librerías .jar. Espero te sirva.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, dentro del enlace que usted mandó tiene la respuesta a mi pregunta.

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas algo como Maven para gestionar las dependencias?

Comment: Porque uso una biblioteca que se actualiza constantemente. La versión antigua de ella no tiene un repositorio, y es la antigua que uso. Sólo tiene repositorios pero recientes. Si utilizo maven solo voy a recoger las más actualizadas, así que sólo consigo con ella `.jar`

Comment: Mira este video, estoy seguro que te ayudara mucho: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=avuCcDkzw2U&ab_channel=HiZTech